# Plotting probability on horizontal greyscale graph from single variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create horizontal stack graph like below[image: Example graph]

Arr1, Arr2, Arr3, Arr4 are in range 0-1 and length is about 50000 each.

Short Example of length 10:

| Array | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arr1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.7 | 0.7 | 0.4 | 0.7 |
| Arr2 | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.5 | 0.1 |
| Arr3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.7 | 0.7 | 0.7 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.1 | 0.2 |
| Arr4 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.2 | 0.1 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.9 |
| B | a | a | a | b | b | b | a | a | a | b |

How can I plot each Arr1, Arr2, Arr3, Arr4 from light to dark based on their value in horizontal graph (or greyscale with each value be different shade of grey).

The values closer to 0 will me light in color and values closer to 1 will be dark. 0 will be white and 1 will black when using greyscale.

In picture Arr1: low values will be light yellow and high values will be dar yellow(all values are between 0 and 1)

Last bar is different, `Array: B` is list of `a` and `b`, how can I plot different color for each occurrence of `a` and `b`.

In picture for B:  occurrences of `a` will be colored `green` and occurrences of `b` will be colored `pink`.

I would not worry much about the layout of the outer box, I would just use `ggarrange` to put all graph in a single plot

What I tried for `Array B`

```
B=c(rep("a",1000),rep("b",1000),rep("a",1000))

df=data.frame(B)
df$ID <- seq.int(nrow(df))
df$char=as.numeric(factor(B))

ggplot(df, aes(x=ID,y = char, color = cut(char, breaks = c(0, 1, 2))))+geom_col()+coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('red','green'),limits=c('(0,1]', '(1,2]'))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = 'letter'))
```

But legends are not perfect
[image: output graph]

The array `B` is important I cannot get the x-axis right or proper scale with

```
  melt(id.vars = "Array") %>%
  mutate(variable = str_extract(variable, "[0-9]+")) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(
    value == "a" ~ -1,
    value == "b" ~ 2, 
    TRUE ~ as.numeric(value)
  )) %>%
  mutate(zz = 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Array, y = variable, group = Array, fill = value)) +
  geom_col() + coord_flip()
```

I guess the `variable` is not set correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, with your sample data inclusding `Array` and etc, you may try

```r
df %>% 
  melt(id.vars = "Array") %>%
  mutate(variable = str_extract(variable, "[0-9]+")) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(
    value == "a" ~ -1,
    value == "b" ~ 2, 
    TRUE ~ as.numeric(value)
  )) %>%
  mutate(zz = 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Array, y = variable, group = Array, fill = value)) +
  geom_col() + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Second, you would be better to use `fill` instead of `color`, that's why your legend looks weird. Also, as you use `fill`, you should use `scale_fill_manual` this time. For example,

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=ID,y = char, fill = cut(char, breaks = c(0, 1, 2))))+geom_col()+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','green'),limits=c('(0,1]', '(1,2]'))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = 'letter'))
```

[image]

#You may try

```
library(RColorBrewer)
df2 <- df %>% 
  melt(id.vars = "Array") %>%
  mutate(variable = str_extract(variable, "[0-9]+"))  %>%
  filter(value %in% c("a","b")) %>%
  mutate(col = value)

df3 <- df %>% 
  melt(id.vars = "Array") %>%
  mutate(variable = str_extract(variable, "[0-9]+"))  %>%
  filter(!value %in% c("a","b")) %>%
  mutate(col = cut(as.numeric(value), 6))

plot.df <- rbind(df2, df3)  
yourScale <- c(brewer.pal(6, "Greys"), "green", "pink")
plot.df %>%
  mutate(variable = as.numeric(variable)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Array, y = variable, group = Array, fill = col)) +
  geom_col() + coord_flip() +
  scale_colour_manual("col", values = yourScale)
```

Comment: how can I get different legend for the ```Array: B``` for corresponding letter to the color? its fine if it is a different graph. Also the x axis looks different

Comment: @RahilVora I forgot to change `variable` as numeric. It will make x axis looks same. I'll reply again after I give you the legend for `B`.

Comment: @RahilVora I add a new code but I think that it's not likely you wanted. It was pretty hard to color scale mixed of continuous and discrete.

Comment: Hi @Park, the x axis is still messed up even after converting variable to numeric. As you can see for B variable in Blue shades does not have same size for same number of a and b(3 'a' and 3'b'). I am okay working with first code with single df